# Listen for user inputs on Messenger

Tags: php, events, facebook-messenger

I'm developing a chatbot on messenger with PHP. I'm not using any 3rd party services like Chatfuel etc.

Whenever, I need a user input, I'm currently storing the question with a key in Redis and sending the response. Then, in the next request, I'm checking if I have that Redis variable stored on my server. Then, I'm processing that user input and deleting the Redis variable.

The problem is that I'm checking for the Redis variables for every webhook request.

Is there any other efficient way to handle the user inputs? I also want to deploy the chatbot on other platforms like Telegram, Skype etc. So, is there a generic event-driven system which would recognise that the incoming webhook request is an answer to a previously asked question?

Comment: Can you post your code to show how you handle webhook?

Comment: There is no other way, store variable of your step of a user flow and generate answers based on it. 
Some systems can pass this variable with a response as custom data, but IMHO this is the wrong way.

Comment: Redis isn't going to be your slow point here.